# Python haystack and needle

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this code to work. When user inputs in a "qwqwqw" and in b "qw" then I need it to output "3" not "2" like it does now. It probably reads q and w separately but I need it to search the exact phrase or letter user inputs in b. And I need it to search from a. How could I change the code to make it work. I have come this far and don't have any more thoughts what to change... And I can't use any text comparing methods like count or findall. Here is my code so far:

```
    a = input("String1: ")
    b = input("String2: ")

    common = {}
    if len(a)>len(b):
        for letter in a:
            if letter in b:
               common[letter]=1

   print (len(common))
```

Comment: When you input _"qwqwqw"_ where? To input `a`? Input `b`? Both? Please prepare unambiguous problem description and [MCVE].

Comment: You are counting the letters in common. If you input "qwqwqw" for a and b, they have "q" and "w" in common, so there are 2.

Comment: `if a == 'qwqwqw': print('3')`

Comment: Please try using [this tool](https://github.com/alexmojaki/askso) to help you write a clear question.

Comment: If user inputs "qwqwqw" in a and "qw" in b? I want to count how many times does input b occures in input a...

Comment: Please do not add extra information in the comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Maybe, `a.count(b)`?

Comment: No, I can't use any text comparing methods like count or findall or something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foo = 'qwqwqw'
bar = 'wq'

idx = 0
counter = 0

while True:
    try:
        # find the next instance of bar, starting at idx
        found_at = foo.index(bar, idx)

        # move idx to the next possible position (after the instance of bar)
        idx = found_at + len(bar)

        # increase the counter
        counter += 1
    except ValueError:
        # foo.index(bar) will raise ValueError if bar cannot be found.  that
        # means we are done
        break

print counter
```